# Argument of type 'Class' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AggregateRoot<IEvent>'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a problem with my `CommandHandler`. I receive an error that I can't solve. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

> Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'AggregateRoot'.   Type 'User' is missing the following
> properties from type 'AggregateRoot':
> [IS_AUTO_COMMIT_ENABLED], [INTERNAL_EVENTS]ts(2345)

```js
// user.repository.ts
...

@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
        super(User, dataSource.createEntityManager());
    }

    async createUser(userRegisterDto: UserRegisterDto) {
        const id = uuidv4();
        const user = await this.save(
            super.create({ ...{ id }, ...userRegisterDto }),
        );
        user.create();
        return user;
    }

    async updateUser(userDto: UserDto) {
        const updatedUser = await super.findOne({
            where: { id: userDto.id },
        });

        updatedUser.update();

        return updatedUser;
    }

    async deleteUser(userDto: UserDto) {
        const deletedUser = await super.findOne({
            where: { id: userDto.id },
        });

        deletedUser.delete();

        return await super.delete(userDto.id);
    }
}
```

```js
// create-user.handler.ts
...

@CommandHandler(CreateUserCommand)
export class CreateUserHandler implements ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand> {
    constructor(
        private readonly _repository: UserRepository,
        private readonly _publisher: EventPublisher,
    ) {}

    async execute(command: CreateUserCommand): Promise<void> {
        Logger.log('Async CreateUserHandler...', 'CreateUserCommand');

        await this._repository
            .findOne({ where: { email: command.userRegisterDto.email } })
            .then((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    throw new HttpException(
                        'User with this email already exists',
                        HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                    );
                }
            });

        const { userRegisterDto } = command;
        const user = this._publisher.mergeObjectContext(
            await this._repository.createUser(userRegisterDto),
        );

        user.commit();
    }
}
```

My User extends an AbstractEntity. And in AbstractEntity I extend AggregateRoot:

```js
// abstract.entity.ts
'use strict';
import { AggregateRoot } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { IAggregateEvent } from 'nestjs-eventstore';
import {
    CreateDateColumn,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

export abstract class AbstractEntity extends AggregateRoot<IAggregateEvent> {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id!: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'created_at' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'updated_at' })
    updatedAt: Date;

    abstract toDto();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `User` model does not extends `AggregateRoot`. Check [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs#events) where the example is:

```js
export class Hero extends AggregateRoot {
  constructor(private id: string) {
    super();
  }
```

Two values missed (`IS_AUTO_COMMIT_ENABLED`  and `INTERNAL_EVENTS`) are into `AggregateRoot` class. Check the [implementation](https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/blob/master/src/aggregate-root.ts). So extending should have these values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I've been thinking about it too. But no, I tried everything, without success.

I have updated my subject. I added a piece of my code.